# bookmark+: after emacs restart the bmkp-jump-dired/bmkp-jump wont work before visiting buffers

Tags: config, bookmarks, hydra

this is a weird issue regarding [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus). after an emacs restart the `bmkp-jump-dired`/`bmkp-jump-1` functions wont work (when I launch them via a command such as in a hydra) before visiting the buffers.

This is what i see in my message buffer:

```
Loaded /home/zeltak/.emacs.d/settings.el
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Invalid face reference: quote [24 times]
bmkp-jump-1: No bookmark specified
```

anyone else has this issues or know what causes this?

Answer (score 1):

Do they work without using your hydra? If so, the hydra is likely where your problem is. Please try to provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`, using a simple bookmark file (even with just one bookmark), and saying what you expect to see at each step and what you do see instead.

The error raised from `bmkp-jump-1` says that it was not given a bookmark to jump to. That suggests that the code invoking it (or invoking a [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) function that calls it) might be to blame - perhaps your hydra.

And the first error message (from where?), which is repeated 24 times (!) suggests that some code (that expected a face) was instead passed a *quoted* face symbol instead of a face symbol (after evaluation). This suggests that the quoted face symbol was either inside a list (e.g. `(some list 'my-face)`) or that it was used in a macro call (macros do not evaluate their arguments). (Does your hydra perhaps have 24 heads?)

Please *show some code*.

Comment: sorry for the late response @drew  (..life got in the way..). so i dont think its a hydra issue. i loaded a new emacs..and tried to EVAL (bmkp-dired-jump "o.food" ) and i still get the same error. i also tried EVALING   (bookmark-jump "o.grants" ) with the same results.

Comment: Im a bit confused on the emacs -Q way to report back. should i launch emacs -Q, then load bookmark+, then eval the bookmark-jump with old bookmark file? should i backup old file and create new one? would you mind helping out on the steps needed?

Comment: ok another observation: again if i launch emacs EVALING ``(bmkp-dired-jump "o.food" ) `` wont work and give the error BUT launching M-x bookmark-jump and choosing the o.food bookmark works well. is that a clue?

Comment: To debug this, please send email offline: `M-x customize-group bookmark-plus` and click `Send Bug Report`. Provide a *step-by-step* recipe, starting with `emacs -Q`. That means `emacs -Q`, load Bookmark+, provide a simple bookmark file (e.g. with a single bookmark), list the keys you press etc. to repro the problem. If you need to load some other code to repro the problem, include that in your steps. Thx.